# My Stack Overflow Careers profile has disappeared. How can I regain access?

Tags: support, jobs, login

I was invited to make a Stack Overflow Careers profile on March 2nd 2015, so I made a profile and populated it with some content and verified my email address.

Today I logged in and found that I no longer have a Careers profile - it says I need to be invited. How can I regain access to my Careers profile?

Answer (score 4):

In the Login page of Careers, click the "Don't remember your account or password" link:

> [image]

Then you can write your email, and hopefully get your account details in there.

Comment: This doesn't help me. When I enter my email address it says there isn't an existing account for my email address, even though I created a profile page through an invitation sent directly to that email address.

Comment: Well, you might get faster and better response by emailing the team then, see the email in the "forgot password" page as well. They do monitor this site of course, but probably not as often as their inbox.

Comment: Thanks I'll try contacting the team that way.